# Move two scrollViews with one swipe

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my project,I have two ScrollViews, one on top of the other.
When i swipe to move the scroll on top, i want the one on the back to move simultaneously.

I tried to move using anchoredPosition, which moved the back scroll but it wasnt exactly at the same position as the one in front.

```
private void Update()
    {
        scrollBack.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = scrollTop.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition;
    }
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: `anchoredPosition` depends on the setting for `Pivot` and `Anchor` in both `RectTransform` components. However `RectTransform` inherits from `Transform` so you also could simply do `scrollBack.transform.position = scrollTop.transform.position`

Comment: @derHugo it gives the same result as the anchoredPostion, the back scroll moves but its not aligned with the front scroll!

Comment: It's hard to tell without having your project in front ... do theirs scales match? Are they using the same anchor and pivot settings? Maybe you could also try `scrollBack.normalizedPosition = scrollTop.normalizedPosition` assuming here `scrollBack` and `scrollTop` are the according `ScrollRect` components instead of the content

Comment: @derHugo the two are identical, in fact the one on top is a duplicate of the one on the back. using the normalizedPosition doesnt move the back scroll!
using transform or anchrodPosition worked but there was a gap the get bigger when you scroll further in the top scroll, i need a fix for that

Comment: Why not give the two ScrollViews a common parent transform in the hierarchy that takes care of the swipe?

Comment: @BenjaminZach can you please explain more? the scrollview does have the same parent but i dont undrestand how to use same swipe for both

Comment: I've just realized that I'm at fault